# Проблема при выводе кирилических символов из таблици mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Запись в табл

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (namen,news,img1,img2,img3,img4,user,moderate)
VALUES ('$namen','$news','$apend1','$apend2','$apend3','$apend4','$user','0')") or die('ошибка');
```

Вывод:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE moderate = '1'");
```

таблица cp1251_general_ci
выдаёт РќР°Р·РІР°РЅРёРµ СЃС‚Р°С‚СЊРё

Comment: В какой кодировке документ? Какая кодировка в БД? И последнее - в самой таблице такие же иероглифы или нормално читаемый текст?

Comment: В самой таблице (в phpmyadmin) нормально отображаеться,
документ cp1251

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроме того, что предложил [[[[@Anovoselof](/users/7384/anovoselof)](/users/7384/anovoselof)](/users/7384/anovoselof)](/users/7384/anovoselof) , попробуйте в .htaccess прописывать строку

```
AddDefaultCharset cp1251
```

[[[[@Anovoselof](/users/7384/anovoselof)](/users/7384/anovoselof)](/users/7384/anovoselof)](/users/7384/anovoselof), поправочка - *mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");* не перед всеми запросами, а после подключения к БД. И после него еще один запрос можно добавить:

```
mysql_query ("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'CP1251_GENERAL_CI'");
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй перед всеми запросами сделать это

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");
```

и в самом начале PHP скрипта

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");
```

Старайся, что бы во всех документах и таблицах была одна кодировка. Лучше конечно использовать UTF8

Comment: давно пора переходить на utf8